# Verificar acesso a internet

Tags: ios, swift

Como posso verificar no meu aplicativo (`swift`) se o usuário tem acesso a internet?

Comment: [Esse código](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30743763/1216394) funciona perfeitamente aqui.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues eu crio uma classe e chamo um metodo ou posso por em uma classe que ja tenho (lembrando que a que tenho herda viewController) ?

Comment: O bom é você criar essa classe e então chamar este método sendo estático, como `Reachability. isConnectedToNetwork ()`. Assim você pode usá-lo em qualquer lugar, não só neste sua *ViewController*.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues desculpe minha ignorancia como poderia fazer esta importação p? pois criei em um arquivo swift e ele não me permitiu importar (como o import) ? e esse codigo me retorna true ou false para a internet ?

Comment: Na Reachability (https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) você pode ficar monitorando a internet, caso ela caia... e também pode saber se está conectado no Wifi ou 3G :)

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que você tenha uma classe para métodos úteis para acessar de forma estática, seria mais ou menos assim uma classe `Functions.swift`:

```
import SystemConfiguration

struct Functions {

    static func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }
        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }

}
```

E então, em suas classes de visualização, teria algo assim (com *Swift*, nesta situação você não precisa importar a classe `Functions`):

```
if Functions.isConnectedToNetwork() {
    print("tem internet")
} else {
    print("nao tem internet")
}
```

O retorno é um `boolean`, então ele diz se existe ou não acesso à internet, seja por *wifi* ou rede de celular.